# selected index value of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have a very simple dropdownlist in a webpart as below.When I run this webpart the Dropdownlist always has One selected but I was thinking -1 makes it not select any value.Am I doing something wrong here.

```
DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
list.Items.Add("One");
list.Items.Add("Two");
list.Items.Add("Three");
list.SelectedIndex = -1;
this.Controls.Add(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an item like "-- SELECT --" and make it selected as default

```
DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
list.Items.Add("-- SELECT --");
list.Items.Add("One");
list.Items.Add("Two");
list.Items.Add("Three");
list.SelectedIndex = 0;
this.Controls.Add(list);
```

Also look into DropDownList.ClearSelection() method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not sure why it's not working..I have seen many places where dropdown fields have nothing selected.

Comment: Actually it's just as nothing is selected, but usually something was selected. As above code, just check if the `SelectedIndex` is 0, then it means nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, but it seems to be strange behavior with the ddl control, the drop down list always selected the item in 0 position.

```
        DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
        list.Items.Add("");
        list.Items.Add("One");
        list.Items.Add("Two");
        list.Items.Add("Three");
        this.form1.Controls.Add(list);
        list.SelectedIndex = 0;
```